# Preventing Authenticated Users from Accessing Login and Sing up Pages in Next.js with NextAuth.js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next-auth

I'm working on a Next.js application with NextAuth.js for authentication. I want to prevent authenticated users from accessing the login and signup pages, redirecting them to another page (e.g., dashboard) instead.

Here's what I've tried so far:

Created a custom AuthRedirectWrapper component that checks for the user's session using getSession from NextAuth.js and handles redirection.
Wrapped the login page component with the AuthRedirectWrapper component to prevent authenticated users from accessing the login page.
However, I still notice a brief flicker of the login page before the redirection occurs. How can I prevent this flicker and ensure that authenticated users are immediately redirected away from the login page?

Comment: You can render the login page on the server with getServerSideProps.

Comment: @aleksa_95
Do you know how can I do that, because my login page is a client component

I used Next.js 13.4 version

Comment: Here's the link with more info: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/get-server-side-props

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think you should implement middleware.